# Point в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Разбираю Match3 игру для Unity, нашёл код, работает. 
Увидел вот такие строчки

```
//структура описание точки 
struct Point
{
    public int X, Y;
}
//список претендентов на уничтожение 
List<Point> Pretindent = new List<Point>();


//генератор координат которые нужно проверить
List<Point> IndexList(Point coord)
{
    //создаем список предпологаемых мест для поиска точки
    List<Point> P = new List<Point>();
    //обьявляем переменную которая будет расчетным буфером для точки 
    Point T;
```

Полная версия кода

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LoadGame : MonoBehaviour
{

//эталонный блок для поля
public GameObject Box;
//размеры поля 
static int col = 8, row = 8;

//карта из блоков
GameObject[,] map = new GameObject[col, row];

//структура описание точки 
struct Point
{
    public int X, Y;
}

//список претендентов на уничтожение 
List<Point> Pretindent = new List<Point>();


//генератор координат которые нужно проверить
List<Point> IndexList(Point coord)
{
    //создаем список предпологаемых мест для поиска точки
    List<Point> P = new List<Point>();
    //обьявляем переменную которая будет расчетным буфером для точки 
    Point T;

    //проверяем существует ли вобще точка в том раене где хотим проверять
    if ((coord.X - 1) >= 0)
    {
        //расчитываем координату по Х
        T.X = coord.X - 1;
        //Расчитываем координату по Y
        T.Y = coord.Y;
        //Добавляем координату в массив
        P.Add(T);
        Debug.Log("ss" + T);

    };

    if ((coord.X + 1) < col)
    {
        //расчитываем координату по Х
        T.X = coord.X + 1;
        //Расчитываем координату по Y
        T.Y = coord.Y;
        //Добавляем координату в массив
        P.Add(T);
        Debug.Log("ss" + T);
    };

    if ((coord.Y - 1) >= 0)
    {
        //расчитываем координату по Х
        T.X = coord.X;
        //Расчитываем координату по Y
        T.Y = coord.Y - 1;
        //Добавляем координату в массив
        P.Add(T);
        Debug.Log("ss" + T);
    };
    if ((coord.Y + 1) < row)
    {
        //расчитываем координату по Х
        T.X = coord.X;
        //Расчитываем координату по Y
        T.Y = coord.Y + 1;
        //Добавляем координату в массив
        P.Add(T);
        Debug.Log("ss" + T);
    };



    //возвращаем найденный список точек 
    return P;
}


void CreateGamePole()
{
    float Dx = 1.2f, Dy = 1.2f;
    Vector3 MyPoze = new Vector3(-7.6f, -4.35f, 0);

    for (int YY = 0; YY < row; YY++)
    {
        for (int XX = 0; XX < col; XX++)
        {

            map[XX, YY] = Instantiate(Box, MyPoze, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; ;
            //получаем параметры блока
            MyPoze.x += Dx;
            BoxBehaviourScript CXCY = map[XX, YY].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>();
            CXCY.CX = XX;
            CXCY.CY = YY;

            CXCY.MyMainGame = this.gameObject;

        }
        //обнуляем позицию Х
        MyPoze.x = -7.6f;
        //задаем новые координаты для У
        MyPoze.y += Dy;

    }
}


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    CreateGamePole();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    MoverDown();
    swap();
}

//функция будет получать номер блока на который нажали 
public void GetSelectIndex(int X, int Y)
{
    BoxBehaviourScript CXCY = map[X, Y].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>();


    Pretindent.Clear();

    Point P;
    P.X = X;
    P.Y = Y;

    TestBlock(P, CXCY.index);
    //проверяем сколько блоков найдено рядом 
    if (Pretindent.Count > 2) ClearBlockColor();
}
void TestBlock(Point coord, int IDColor)
{
    //проверяем нет ли уже этой точки в списке на вылет 
    int Find = Pretindent.IndexOf(coord);
    //если не нашли значение значит равно -1
    if (Find == -1)
    {
        //получим цвет проверяемого блока 
        int IndexColor = map[coord.X, coord.Y].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>().index;
        //если точка  
        if (IndexColor == IDColor)
        {
            //добавляем претиндента в список 
            Pretindent.Add(coord);
            //расчитываем координаты для поиска далее 
            List<Point> Test = IndexList(coord);
            //запускаем цикл поиска по точкам 
            foreach (Point T in Test) TestBlock(T, IDColor);
        }

    }
}

void ClearBlockColor()
{
    //Закрасим белым цветом все найденные точки 
    foreach (Point Clear in Pretindent)
    {
        //обнулим точки с правельным цветом 
        map[Clear.X, Clear.Y].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>().index = 0;
    }
}

//функция сброса блоков вниз 
void MoverDown()
{
    for (int Y = 0; Y < row; Y++)
    {
        for (int X = 0; X < col; X++)
        {
            //проверяем пуст ли блок 
            if (map[X, Y].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>().index == 0)
            {
                int Dy = Y + 1;
                //проверяем может ли над нами быть кубик
                if (Dy < row)
                {
                    map[X, Y].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>().index = map[X, Dy].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>().index;
                    map[X, Dy].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>().index = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    map[X, Y].GetComponent<BoxBehaviourScript>().RandomColor();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос вот в чем - несмотря на прекрасную комментированность кода, "структура описание точки" для меня совершенно непонятно. Вроде как в Match3 ищутся GameObject-ы и уничтожаются, если рядом. Что за точки

```
 struct point
```

и для чего они тут нужны? В чем их преимущество перед просто поиском GameObject и сверкой по координатам?

Comment: видимо оптимизация - это быстрее скорее всего чем каждый раз искать GameObject.

Comment: @pavel я видимо некорректно сформулировал вопрос. Зачем вообще эти точки? Чем они являются и как взаимодействуют с GameObject? Как через них можно найти или уничтожить объект?

Comment: мало информации. Я бы сделал двумерный массив со всеми игровыми объектами нужными а работал с их координатами.

Comment: @pavel Добавил полную версию кода

Comment: ну собственно я был прав. Чтобы для индексации массива `map`

Comment: @pavel Ну вот, а можете объяснить механизм как это происходит? Вместо геймобджектов добавляем в массив координаты их, всё верно? 
И после того как мы имеем координаты всех объектов, как нам совершать с ними действия?